# Nginx server returns strange characters

Tags: nginx

I setup nginx reverse proxy server listening 80 port, which forward requests to another nginx. 
When I try to open site in chrome in incognito mode all is ok, but if I open site on localhost chrome shows

This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.

when I enter in address bar localhost:80, nginx logs following output

```
nginx_1     | 172.28.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2019:12:52:32 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\
x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03H\x8D\x93\xB5e\xE2\x05\xF7\
xCF\xA3N\xEB\xBF\x9B\x86\xACQX\xBF\xB7\x92\x1B#\xEAV\x0F_\x86\xFC\xC1\xC
5R \x93\x88/`\x889\xA2\xBC\xDD\xFD\xDA\x8E\xA8f\xC3\xBA\xC5CwNQ\x80\xFC\xA9
\x8Cy\xAB,_\x95j\xB2\x00\x22\xDA\xDA\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\x
C0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x00" 
400 157 "-" "-" "-"
```

My proxy server config

```
upstream frontend_server {
  server frontend:3000;
}

upstream backend_server {
  server backend:4000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name no_name;


  location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://frontend_server/;
  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://backend_server/;
  }

}
```

Second nginx server

```
server {

  listen 3000;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you ensure you're connecting to `http://localhost:80` and not `https://localhost:80`.  If you've accidently typed http**S** then nginx console may show similar output.

Comment: Hm, I just noticed, my browser replace  `http://localhost:80/` with `https://localhost//`

Comment: How can this be solved?

Comment: Assuming you're not using something like HTTPS-Everywhere, then maybe clearing the cache.  Sounds like some kind of auto complete.  Maybe try an incognitio tab and be sure it enter the URL exactly with the `http` part.